# Does Ubuntu 13.04 support AVX instruction set?

Tags: 13.04

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I want to know if it supports AVX Instruction set. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Intel AVX is a new-256 bit instruction set extension to Intel® SSE and is designed for applications that are Floating Point (FP) intensive. It was released early 2011 as part of the Intel® micro-architecture code name Sandy Bridge processor family and is present in platforms ranging from notebooks to servers. Intel AVX improves performance due to wider vectors, new extensible syntax, and rich functionality. This results in better management of data and general purpose applications like image, audio/video processing, scientific simulations, financial analytics and 3D modeling and analysis.<sup>[Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-isa-extensions)</sup>

AVX is supported since kernel version 2.6.30, which was released on June 9, 2009.

Here is the kernel version used by Ubunut 13.04;

```
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Hence it supports the AVX Instruction set